# Rummy version with a run of seven as last round

Tags: identify-this-game, gin-rummy

I've been trying to remember the details on a gin rummy game I played when I was younger. This game had the last round require a "run of seven" and a set of three.  Looking at Wikipedia I see [Contract Rummy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contract_rummy) which is similar but doesn't have this requirement for the last round. Does anyone know what flavor of rummy was represented by this type of last round?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you've already found the answer: it's a form of contract rummy, just with a different final contract than the one listed on the Wiki entry.

From the [contract rummy](http://www.rummy-games.com/rules/contract-rummy.html) entry on rummy-games.com :

> The rules detailed below are representative of all Contract Rummy
>   games, though there are numerous regional and local variations even
>   among games with the same name.

Incidentally, that particular contract (7+3) appears as one of the contracts in [Shanghai Rummy](http://www.rummy-games.com/rules/shanghai-rummy.html) (but not the last).